# Create a maven project module tree?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I'm looking for a quick way, for any given multi-module project, to show a quick overview of the project hierarchy including only the modules in the project, excluding external dependencies.

eg for a project

```
project root
+- A
   +- B
      +- C
   +- D 
      +- E
         +- F
+- G
   +- H
```

I would like to see a quick, single screen view for A-H (like it is depicted here) that gives me a fast digestible view to get an idea of a project structure. Ideally it would be command line output, not a platform specific solution (I note there is a tool for VisualStudio).

`mvn dependency:tree` is great but too verbose for this case, I suppose I could `grep` and `cut` the output apart but feels like there should be an easier way (ie another plugin).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can filter the dependency tree: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/filtering-the-dependency-tree.html

So, if your group ID was `com.foo.bar`, you could get the projects in that group ID with:

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=com.foo.bar
```

Assuming all of your project's modules are within that group, that would cover your use case.

Comment: For me mvn dependency:tree doesn't work as supposed.
If I have A that depends on B and C, and B that depends on C, maven dependency:tree shows me that A depends on B and C, but nothing about B depending on C.

Comment: @Uberto try mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose

Answer (score 1):

You could try this module here: [MavenStructurePlugin](https://github.com/buraksarac/MavenStructurePlugin)
I had the same problem as you did and found it quite useful.

The output is pretty much what you seem to want:

```
            test
            |
            |__ a
            |
            |__ b
            |
            |
            \__ c
                |
                |__ d
                |
                |__ e
                |
                |__ f
```